# I need an example of working goto use in python please. None of the examples I have seen will compile

Tags: python, windows, goto

Please don't tell me why I shouldn't use goto as I have a very specific reason that I must use it. Let's just say I'm converting an assembler x386 program that is in live use so I have to convert that code continually. Until this is running I don't have the luxury of completely converting/rewriting the program.

Python 3.9.2 x64 on W10 and pip install goto-statement. I have also tried with 3.7.3 x32 on another W10 PC.

None of the examples I have found online will work. They all generate various errors.

```
# from goto import goto, label
import goto

ch = input("Enter 'a', 'b' or 'c': ")
if ch == 'a':
    # goto .a
    goto(a)
elif ch == 'b':
    goto .b
else:
    goto .quit

# label .a
# a:
.a
print("You typed 'a'")
goto .quit

label .b
print("You typed 'b'")
goto .quit

label .quit
print("Finished\n")
```

The statement "from goto import goto, label" fails.

The statement "import goto" doesn't generate an error.

"goto .a" fails with AttributeError: module 'goto' has no attribute 'a'

"goto(a)" fails with NameError: name 'a' is not defined (with "label.a")

"a:" fails with SyntaxError: invalid syntax

".a"fails with SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The last release of `goto-statement` [was in 2018](https://pypi.org/project/goto-statement/) and the last supported version seems to be Python 3.6. Also, at the first glance, this syntax should only be available in functions decorated with `@with_goto`

Comment: @with_goto was also tried and failed. Surely there is a working example somewhere that illustrates the syntax?

Comment: `goto-statement` patches Python's bytecode. It could very well be that Python 3.7 introduced changes to its bytecode that broke `goto-statement`. Anyway, Python doesn't have `goto` statements, and this library is more of a hack and a proof-of-concept (Python _could_ have `goto` if the devs wanted it to).